# Find path of jar file in GCP

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, jar, reducers, mapper

Find the path of hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar jar file in Google File Platform.

https://github.com/devangpatel01/TF-IDF-implementation-using-map-reduce-Hadoop-python-

I am trying to run this mapreduce on GCP using hadoop, but i'm not able to find the path of hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar. I tried to download the jar file manually and upload it in hadoop and then run the mapper1.py. But i'm getting error saying the path is wrong. The above program was run on a local machine. How do i edit the command to run it on GCP?

hadoop jar /home/kirthyodackal/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar -input hdfs://cluster-29-m/input_prgs/input_prgs/input1/000000_0 -output hdfs://cluster-29-m/input_prgs/input_prgs/output1 -mapper hdfs://cluster-29-m/input_prgs/input_prgs/mapper1.py -reducer hdfs://cluster-29-m/input_prgs/input_prgs/reducer1.py

Comment: Are you using Dataproc? it's an "almost" managed service,you can enter in the vms but you should send the jobs like stated in the docs:https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-explorer-submit the jarFileUris  field is used to refer to local jars in the master VM

Comment: Yes I am, but I used another mapper-reducer function from https://github.com/SatishUC15/TFIDF-HadoopMapReduce#tfidf-hadoop and it worked fine. I am not really familiar with sending jobs as I just started using Dataproc. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different Mapper-Reducer program and could run the mapreduce. I used the code from https://github.com/SatishUC15/TFIDF-HadoopMapReduce#tfidf-hadoop and run the following commands on my GCP cluster.

```
> hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -file /home/kirthyodackal/MapperPhaseOne.py /home/kirthyodackal/ReducerPhaseOne.py -mapper "python MapperPhaseOne.py" -reducer "python ReducerPhaseOne.py" -input hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mapinput/inputfile -output hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred1

> hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -file /home/kirthyodackal/MapperPhaseTwo.py /home/kirthyodackal/ReducerPhaseTwo.py -mapper "python MapperPhaseTwo.py" -reducer "python ReducerPhaseTwo.py" -input hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred1/part-00000 hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred1/part-00001 hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred1/part-00002 hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred1/part-00003 hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred1/part-00004  -output hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred2

> hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -file /home/kirthyodackal/MapperPhaseThree.py /home/kirthyodackal/ReducerPhaseThree.py -mapper "python MapperPhaseThree.py" -reducer "python ReducerPhaseThree.py" -input hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred2/part-00000 hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred2/part-00001 hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred2/part-00002 hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred2/part-00003 hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappred2/part-00004  -output hdfs://cluster-3299-m/mappredf
```

The following link outlines how I went about MapReduce on GCP.
https://github.com/kirthy21/Data-Analysis-Stack-Exchange-Hadoop-Pig-Hive-MapReduce-TFIDF